# Typescript - How to use nested mapped types

Tags: typescript

I am given a large complicated interface X that I cannot modify, I would like to define some smaller types based on the properties and sub-properties within the interface X that I want to use as types for parameters of a function. I would also like to avoid redeclaring separately what is already inside X.

```js
interface X {
  a:number;
  c:{
    aa:number;
    cc:{
      aaa:string;
    }
  },
  d?:{
    aa:number;
    cc:{
      aaa:string;
    }
  },
  e:{
    aa:number;
    cc:{
      aaa:string;
    }
  }[]
}
```

I understand that I can use mapped types to access the sub-type [*Edit note*: sub-type is the wrong terminology, this should be called **Nested-level types**, see answer below] this should be of the object, for example:

```js
type C = X["c"]; // { aa:number; cc:{ aaa:string } } 

type C_CC = X["c"]["cc"]; // { aaa: string }

type D = X["d"]; // { aa:number; cc:{ aaa:string } } | undefined
```

However, things got a bit hairy when the property is possibly undefined. If I want to get at the type at X.d.cc...(which should give {aaa:string} ) how do I do it? Or is it even possible?

The following two attempts gives an error:

```js
type D_CC1 = X["d"]["cc"];  // error? Due to the (d?) possibly undefined?
type D_CC2 = Required<X["d"]>["cc"];  // error also?
```

Separately, I am also a bit confused when arrays are involved, for example above for E:

```js
type E = X["e"]; // { aa:number; cc:{ aaa:string } }[]
type E_CC1 = X["e"]["cc"]; // error
type E_CC2 = X["e"][0]["cc"]; // got the result I wanted: { aaa: string }
```

The third line seems to work, but I am not sure what is the logic of using [0] -- seems hacky. I would like to know if this is the right way.

**Edit**: Changed type names from D_CC to D_CC1 and D_CC2 to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: I don't have any errors for D_CC. Are you sure you just didn't declare both at once with the same name, thus a duplicate identifier?

Comment: I am getting typescript squiggly lines under ["cc"] with error: **Property 'cc' does not exist on type '{ aa: number; cc: { aaa: string; }; } | undefined'.ts(2339).**

However type `type D_CC3 = Required<X>["d"]["cc"];` works! But is this the right way to do things (using Required<T>)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just a detail but in order to not mix up terminology, what you have in your interface are not subtypes, but nested-level types. Nested-level types have top-level types. Subtypes are types that you can use wherever a type that has this subtype is required.

Next, what you are calling **mapped types** are actually what we call the **keying-in** operator. That's a way to look up property types in a shape.

**Mapped types** are used to map over an object's key and value types and it looks like this:

```
type MyMappedType = {
  [Key in K]: ValueType
}
```

That's also where you could leverage the keyof operator. `Key in keyof Something`

For example, to make all fields in a shape optional (there's a built-in mapped types called `Partial<Object>` for this), you could use `mapped types`:

```
type ShapeAllOptional = {
  [K in keyof MyShape]?: MyShape[K]
}
```

Now on to your question.

```
type D_CC1 = X["d"]["cc"];  // error? Due to the (d?) possibly undefined?
```

You could use something like this

```
type myStype = NonNullable<X['d']>['cc']
```

As to using

```
type E_CC1 = X["e"]["cc"]; // error
type E_CC2 = X["e"][0]["cc"]; // got the result I wanted: { aaa: string }
```

Yes, it's an array with each item having that shape. I don't know if it's hacky but I did see something once that looks a bit "cleaner".

```
type E_CC2 = X["e"][number]["cc"];
```

There's no better way I'm aware of.

Ah, I almost forgot.

```
type D_CC2 = Required<X["d"]>["cc"];  // error also?
```

Careful, what you're saying here is make all properties in X['d'] required, that is `aa` and `cc`, which are... already required. `Required<X>` would I think achieve what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your very detailed explanation - I fully understand now. I like your idea of using conditional types too for D_CC, since using Required<T> seems to be an overkill, but I can't get your code to work: `type D_CC = X['d'] extends undefined ? undefined : X['d']['cc']` . Nevertheless you put me on the right track -- I would think something like `type D_CC =Exclude<X['d'],undefined>['cc'];`?

As for using [0] I also prefer [number] .. I understand why the index needs to be there for the array, just that forcing 0 there seems a bit counter-intuitive!

Comment: You're right, I'm also getting the same error now. I though it would use type refinement or something like that. Instead of using Exclude, you can use NonNullable<X['d']>['cc'], a bit terser :).

Comment: Didn't realise `NonNullable<T>` also excludes undefined. Thanks for that! :)

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at your interface, you'll notice that `e` property is actually defined as array.

```
e:{
    aa:number;
    cc:{
      aaa:string;
    }
}[] // NOTICE THIS!
```

That's the reason you need to use indexer `[0]` to get the type of item of that array. It's not a hack, actually it's added in typescript since 2.1 and the official name is [indexed access types, also called lookup types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#keyof-and-lookup-types).